# Correct way to return value in API if there is no result

Tags: php, json

I am making an API for mobile APP based on PHP backend. I have cases where i return an array list and if there is no results i return a message

where results are found:

```
{"status":"success",
   "data":[{"users_details":[{"user_id":1,"parent_id":2}]}],
  "token":"success"}
```

where are no results found:

```
{"status":"error","data":"no user found","token":"success"}
```

Is this a good approach, If no what should it be?

Comment: Yes it seems good if it's unauthorized requests you can throw  error with HTTP codes

Comment: thank you for your reply. The main concern i had if that if i dont have data. should i return a message "data":"no user found" or a empty array "data":[]

Comment: I have added a detailed answer, check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i prefer to utilise the http response code so for data not found you can return 204 and when you find matches return 200 and the list of the users

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to return a message, that no user data is found, but it would be perfect, if along with the response, a correct response code would be returned. In this case it would be 404 - not found. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes for more info

Comment: thank you for your reply. The main concern i had if that if i dont have data. should i return a message  "data":"no user found" or a empty array "data":[]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you process it, I would simply do this.

```
{"status":"error","msg":"no user found","token":"success"}
```

Because you don't need to get confused with user data and error message.

consider like if the status is an error then it should have detailed error message in **msg** key

so you can eliminate the response before the going into actual user data parsing functions. like

```
if($response['status'] === 'error')
   return "Error Message: " . $status['msg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally stand with empty array. It's normal situation, when API search return no results (and empty array is naturally no results answer). It's okay status for me.

The request may me malformed or there may be problems with database, this is really the case to return status: error.

More to say, when we return in first case array with data and in second string, it is bad approach anyway, cause we have to handle different types of data, it's anti-pattern as I might say. The type should always be the same.

We first check that status is okay or error (no connection, bad connection, bad request etc), then we either check data (empty array = no results) or check error message

```
{"status": "error", "message": "connection error"}

{"status": "success", "data": []}

{"status": "error", "data": ["First result", "Second result"]}
```

It doesn't mean that we cannot redirect user to 404 page f.e. if we get such API result, of course. But as for API request, when empty result is normal outcome it shouldn't be treated as error, or we will be mixing real errors with logic, which is obviously bad.

Comment: can you explain why returning a string with a valid message is not good but returning a non required empty array is ? Is it just because we need to code extra to check if the data is string or array ? I think checks are always good in codes and provides a extra layer of security ?

Comment: Personally I think yes. The logic should be as simple as it can be. Even though PHP is dynamically typed language, variable that can have several types is bad logic in my opinion. Checks provide an extra layer of security yes. But the checks should be when f.e. you have user input and so on, when there is really place for error. Your own variables should be consistent types, and it's checked with test cases, not real code checks.

But this is all a matter of program size, importance etc too, sometimes it isn't worth to adhere to all best practices)

Comment: Though I agree with @Diab also

Comment: Do you mean that in case of no records we will not send data field  and code 204 and in case of records found we will send data field and code 200

Comment: I say that is is possible solution. But I must mention that often we even cannot send data with 204 code response because it's intended for http replies without body, f.e. browsers can reject body in case of 204 and process only headers. So we wouldn't always be able to access 'status' variable also.

Comment: What according to you is a proper json reply with or without data ? Can you please share a example

Comment: As for me, I totally prefer the scheme that I gave in my answer. I just stated that is is also possible to use http statuses heavily, but this also requires some tricks as statuses really aren't indented to know about their content, so it's proposed from HTTP protocol standards, that response with {''status": "error"...} should have status 200, and we will override it. Status 204 says that the request was successfully processed, but no content was sent back. It's ok for the situation that we have no results, but what if we had some recoverable (catched) error on server?

Comment: We have to use another HTTP status again, so we have to use a bunch of HTTP statuses instead of sending just {"status": "error", "message": "some error"}. Not that it is overriding intended HTTP status usage, it also creates a lot of code to check them all.